# Not getting email on second request email verification

Tags: php, email, laravel-5

Recently I add email verification in my Web App from [this blog post](http://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-email-verification-with-activation-code.html#.VyiuoPl96Ul)
My app is working good and I also get an email when user signup but when I try to login without activated I must get an other email from my app but it won't send it. I'm missing something but I didn't find help to resolve this.

This is my AuthController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\ActivationService;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Registration & Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users, as well as the
    | authentication of existing users. By default, this controller uses
    | a simple trait to add these behaviors. Why don't you explore it?
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $activationService;
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */


    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function __construct(ActivationService $activationService)
    {
    $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    $this->activationService = $activationService;
    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    $user = $this->create($request->all());

    $this->activationService->sendActivationMail($user);

    return redirect('/login')->with('status', 'We sent you an activation code. Check your email.');
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }


    public function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
    if (!$user->activated) {
        $this->activationService->sendActivationMail($user);
        auth()->logout();
        return back()->with('warning', 'You need to confirm your account. We have sent you an activation code, please check your email.');
    }
    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }


    public function activateUser($token)
    {
    if ($user = $this->activationService->activateUser($token)) {
        auth()->login($user);
        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
    abort(404);
    }
}
```

Comment: does this condition `!$user->activated` satisfies? and you got log out?

Comment: i need this condition if user not activated than he can't login first confirm verification from email but when i sign up it send email perfectly but i also want when user delete accidently his email he got email again when trying  to login

Comment: I mean, if user not activated, are you able to go inside this condition?